# Masking Textbox input with an IValueConverter without losing data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create a textbox/IValueConverter that would show the user the following lines if they hit 1234 then backspace 3 times.

```
1
*2
**3
***4
***
**
*
```

My biggest issue at the moment is that I am losing data as the IValueConverter is saving "***4" in my ViewModel.

Are there any common strategies for masking input data like this without using a regular PasswordBox?

Comment: Use the right control for the job.  [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy `TextBlock` or `Label` to show the mask, and set the `TextBox` text coloe to transparent. This way the actual data is saved to the model, and the `*` are only displayed in the label.

Something like (very rough example)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication13"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TextToStarConverter x:Key="TextToStarConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" Foreground="Transparent" Text="{Binding MyModelProperty}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=txtbox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToStarConverter}}"  IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Converter (pleae ignore horrible code, its just a demo :))

```
public class TextToStarConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return new string('*', value.ToString().Length -1) + value.ToString().Last().ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sa_ddam213, this was my first approach, but since it doesn't use the textboxes internal ContentPresenter there is no carot shown.

Comment: The caret will be shown with this method, because we only set the forground to Transparent not the Caret brush. see my image update.I have not overridden the style of the TextBox I just overlayed a Label on top.